# What is wrong with this Excel VBA Code problem

Tags: excel, vba

I do not know what is wrong with this Excel VBA code because it works in other sheets. I only changed names to refer to the sheet needed.

```
Sheets("Orders EUR in curs").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("orderseur").PivotFields("Centru_Cost").CurrentPage _
    = "(All)"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("orderseur").PivotFields("Centru_Cost")
    .PivotItems("CENTRU DIVERSE").Visible = False

End With
```

When run I get:

> 1004 error: application defined or object defined error.

When I try to debug this part seems to be the problem:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("orderseur").PivotFields("Centru_Cost").CurrentPage _
    = "(All)"
```

Not sure if it matters but I use Office 2010.

**Update**: As a final option I have deleted the sheet and made it again and now it works. Still I have no idea what was the problem.

Comment: Most likely the pivot table name is not `orderseur`

Comment: I thought of this already and I changed the name to something else but I get the same error. The name is taken from Option Tab, PivotTable Name.

Comment: Record a macro when you do something with that pivot table